# Typescript & react-navigation: Type Information on NavigationContainer ref?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am using react-navigation & I have encountered a use case where I need to navigate from outside a component (navigation after receiving push notification).

The issue is, when using the `navigation.navigate` method from inside a component, I get proper Typescript Autocomplete and Intellisense based on all the types defined as per the documentation.

However, when using the `navigationRef.current?.navigate` method, type information is absent.

Is there any way to bring type information to the ref object too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by providing the generic type to the `navigate` method.

Let's say you have some screens and you declared the route name param list types ([taken from here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript#type-checking-the-navigator)) like this:

```
type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  Profile: { userId: string };
  Feed: { sort: 'latest' | 'top' } | undefined;
};
```

In order to get the type information about these routes in your navigate method, you can consume the above declared type as a generic, like this:

```
// You will now be able to choose between 'Home' or 'Profile' or 'Feed' when invoking your navigate method
navigationRef.current?.navigate<keyof RootStackParamList>('Home');
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue while implementing push notification.What i'm done is, created a navigation helper file (navigationHelper.ts).

```
import * as React from 'react';

export const navigationRef = React.createRef();

export function navigate(name, params) {
    navigationRef.current?.navigate(name, params);
}
```

in AppNavigator.tsx

import {navigate} from './helpers/NavigationHelper';

```js
 messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
          console.log(
            'Notification caused app to open from background state:',
            remoteMessage,
          );
          let data = JSON.parse(remoteMessage?.data?.data);
          if (data?.page == 'ride_detail') {
            navigate('RideDetailsIndex', {id: data?.ride_id});
          }
        });
```